# Virtual keyboard

Tags: linux, keyboard

I am trying to create a virtual keyboard on my Linux machine. The machine has only a CLI. I would like to populate `/dev/input` with another device (something like `/dev/input/event20` or so). I figured out how to do this with `mknod` but unfortunately the major and minor numbers need to be linked to an actual device (making reading and writing to this device impossible via C++). So short of writing my own keyboard driver how can I accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: I don't know much about the Linux input system, but if you can convince a process to read input from a FIFO (created by `mkfifo`) you can write to that with C++ as much as you want

Comment: This won't work for me, I need the device to look like a standard keyboard (just without the physical keyboard) to linux.

Comment: WARNING: SourceForge link — You might want to take a look at the source [to this project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tabletvk/) and see what they did there

Answer (score 4):

You can use `/dev/uhid` to create your own [HID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class) device. This makes it easy not only to provide keyboards from userspace, but also mice, joysticks etc. The newly created HID device will automatically get an associated `/dev/input` device. There's an example program in the kernel sources, `samples/uhid/uhid-example.c`. I think that is the most portable way, HID devices are highly standardized. Basically all USB keyboards and mice are HID devices.

You can also use `/dev/uinput` or `/dev/input/uinput` (depends on your distro) to directly create an input-layer device. See e.g. [here](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput) for details. This needs the `uinput` kernel module.